# unable to safely remove USB HDDs

Tags: 14.04, usb, external-hdd, eject

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and previously did not have any problems with safe removal of USB external storage devices like a 2TB Toshiba Canvio Basics or an older Seagate FreeAgent Go. Now I have bought an Innateck FE2005 USB case for my older 2,5' HDDs and a 2TB Seagate Backup Plus Slim. Both I cannot safely remove. Both spin down, but in a matter of like 2 seconds they power up again, too short to detach the cable. I wonder if a work around exists for that. Or if an upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 might solve this. Right now I have no need to upgrade because everything runs smooth and stable.
Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to upgrade from 14.04.  It's supported and just like 16.04, has the ability to safely remove a removable device that isn't in use.  It's likely that you would experience the same problem with either version under the same conditions.  Can you elaborate on how you are issuing the safe remove command?

Comment: Try connecting the drives to a **powered** USB hub and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: Just by right clicking and choosing the safely remove option.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no USB hub to try this. Since google did not give many results for this problem I am just guessing that it must be some sort of a combination between the USB-host controller and the controller of the external HDD which Ubuntu cannot handle. The Seagate drive should have been sold often enough that more users would have experienced this

Comment: Just found out that safely remove works if connected to USB2.0. But this is not a desirable workaround